# Как создать 100 файлов с именами a1, a2, a3, …. a100 в терминале?

Tags: linux, terminal

Как создать 100 файлов с именами a1, a2, a3, …. a100 в терминале?
Это вообще можно сделать в одну команду?

Comment: Зависит от шелла. `touch a{1..100}` в баше, например

Answer (score 5):

наибольшая «сложность» — получить последовательность чисел. дополнить же их буквами и передать программе `touch` — это просто.

стандартом *posix*, насколько мне известно, каких-либо «бортовых» средств, упрощающих процесс генерации, нет. можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь универсальным языком:

1. с помощью программы *awk*:

   ```
   $ awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=5;i++) printf "a%d\n", i }'
   a1
   a2
   a3
   a4
   a5
   ```

   для создания файлов достаточно передать список программе *touch*:

   ```
   $ touch $(awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=5;i++) printf "a%d\n", i }')
   ```
2. с помощью программы *bc*:

   ```
   $ echo 'for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {print "a",i,"\n"}' | bc
   a1
   a2
   a3
   a4
   a5
   ```

   для создания файлов достаточно передать список программе *touch*:

   ```
   $ touch $(echo 'for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {print "a",i,"\n"}' | bc)
   ```
3. в операционной же системе *gnu* есть программа *seq*, как раз упрощающая генерацию:

   ```
   $ seq -f 'a%g' 1 5
   a1
   a2
   a3
   a4
   a5
   ```

   для создания файлов достаточно передать список программе *touch*:

   ```
   $ touch $(seq -f 'a%g' 1 5)
   ```
4. ну и современные «навороченные» оболочки типа *bash*/*zsh* понимают конструкцию `{1..5}`:

   ```
   $ echo {1..5}
   1 2 3 4 5
   ```

   т.е. можно создать файлы опять-таки передав список программе *touch*:

   ```
   $ touch a{1..5}
   ```